# Magento 2 invoice refund rest api ID required

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I am using /rest/V1/invoice/{id}/refund, but it is giving error " ID required"
The json which I am posting is:

```
  {
  "items": [
    {
      "order_item_id": 2,
      "qty": 40
    }
  ],
  "isOnline": true,
  "notify": true,
  "appendComment": false,
  "comment": {

    "comment": "string",
    "is_visible_on_front": 0
  },
  "arguments": {
    "shipping_amount": 0,
    "adjustment_positive": 0,
    "adjustment_negative": 0,
    "extension_attributes": {
      "return_to_stock_items": [
        0
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Which ID is missing?

Comment: I think order Id is missing

Comment: But there is no property such as "order Id"

Comment: /rest/V1/invoice/{id}/refund here in id you need to add order id value

Comment: when I am passing order id it is giving error "requested entity doesn't exist".  Currently I am passing  "/rest/V1/invoice/17/refund"

Comment: Have you referred this  : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/get-started/order-tutorial/order-issue-refund.html

Comment: Thank you I just checked. Now I am passing order id but still the same error "requested entity doesn't exist". I have changed payload also

Comment: Check that order is exist or not!

Comment: Yes it is existing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try following code:**

> REST API: /V1/order/:orderId/refund

```
Method: POST
URL: http://www.domain.com/rest/V1/order/[ORDER_ID]/refund

{
  "items": [
    {
      "order_item_id": [ORDER_ITEM_ID],
      "qty": [ORDER_ITEM_REFUND_QTY]
    }
  ],
  "notify": true,
  "arguments": {
    "shipping_amount": 0,
    "adjustment_positive": 0,
    "adjustment_negative": 0,
    "extension_attributes": {
      "return_to_stock_items": [
        [ORDER_ITEM_ID]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

> REST API: /V1/invoice/:invoiceId/refund

```
Method: POST
URL: http://www.domain.com/rest/V1/invoice/[INVOICE_ID]/refund

{
  "items": [
    {
      "order_item_id": [ORDER_ITEM_ID],
      "qty": [ORDER_ITEM_REFUND_QTY]
    }
  ],
  "is_online": false,
  "notify": true,
  "arguments": {
    "shipping_amount": 0,
    "adjustment_positive": 0,
    "adjustment_negative": 0,
    "extension_attributes": {
      "return_to_stock_items": [
        [ORDER_ITEM_ID]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you its working now, but when I am trying to refund a order it always refund "offline". Is there any way to refund whole order "online"?

Comment: As it says for offline refund you have to use REST API: /V1/order/:orderId/refund.

And for online, use REST API: /V1/invoice/:invoiceId/refund.

For more information you can refer this [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/get-started/order-tutorial/order-issue-refund.html)